# How to convert databaseClient result into object?

Tags: converters, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

I have a task to insert entity through r2dbc database client, and convert the result (map) into the entity.
I want to do it this way:

```
databaseClient.insert().into(ApplicationData.class)
            .using(applicationData)
            .map(converter.populateIdIfNecessary(applicationData))
            .first();
```

But the problem is **converter** entity *MappingR2dbcConverter* isn't created by spring.
So, I decided to create it myself:

```
@Bean
public MappingR2dbcConverter converter(RelationalMappingContext mappingContext,
                                                             R2dbcCustomConversions r2dbcCustomConversions)....
```

My question, is it correct way to convert result map into entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R2dbc DatabaseClient will be part of Spring framework 5.3, see [My example for Spring 5.3 M2](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-r2dbc-sample/blob/master/database-client/src/main/java/com/example/demo/PostRepository.java#L22).

```java
public static final BiFunction<Row, RowMetadata, Post> MAPPING_FUNCTION = (row, rowMetaData) -> Post.builder()
            .id(row.get("id", UUID.class))
            .title(row.get("title", String.class))
            .content(row.get("content", String.class))
            .status(row.get("status", Post.Status.class))
            .metadata(row.get("metadata", Json.class))
            .createdAt(row.get("created_at", LocalDateTime.class))
            .build();

public Flux<Post> findAll() {
        return this.databaseClient
                .sql("SELECT * FROM posts")
                .filter((statement, executeFunction) -> statement.fetchSize(10).execute())
                .map(MAPPING_FUNCTION)
                .all();
    }

    public Mono<Post> findById(UUID id) {
        return this.databaseClient
                .sql("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id=:id")
                .bind("id", id)
                .map(MAPPING_FUNCTION)
                .one();
    }
```